# Matrix norm induced by vector norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, matrix-norms

Recently, I've been studying matrix norms and I came across the matrix norm

$$\|A\| := \sup_{|x| \leqslant 1} |Ax|$$

where

$$|x| := \sqrt{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} |x_{i}|^{2}}$$

where $n$ is the size of matrix. I am interested in properties of this norm in particular the relation between $\|A^{n}\|$ and $\|A\|^{n}$ knowing the eigenvalues of matrix $A$. I'd like to know where can I read about properties of such norm, perhaps there is specific name for that norm? Any help will be greatly appeciated

Comment: All induced matrix-norms are submultiplicative, meaning that $||AB||\le ||A||\cdot||B||$. The wikipedia article about matrix norms should give you what you need.

Comment: You can related the eigenvalues of $A$ with $\|A^n\|^{1/n}$ using the [Gelffand formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius#Gelfand's_formula).

Comment: What is the  "size of matrix"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matrix norms of the type $\text{sup}_{x\in V}\Vert Ax\Vert/\Vert x\Vert$ for some vector norm $\Vert x\Vert$ are sub-multiplicative: $\Vert AB\Vert\le \Vert A\Vert\,\Vert B\Vert$. The particular norm you are referring to, called $l_{2}-$norm, is the maximal spectral element of the matrix $A$, which is the maximal eigenvalue of the diagonal matrix of singular value decomposition. You can learn all these facts from the Wikipedia page on matrix norms. From a practical point of view you can read about this, for example, in "Mathematics for Machine Learning" by Marc Peter Deisenroth et al., but really this is standard material you find in any linear algebra reference book. Also: check out [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vSczTbgc8Rc) video. Also also: Lloyd N. Trefethen and David Bau III, "Numerical Linear Algebra"

Comment: just a question why using $l_2$ with a small l, it is the space of infinite sequences (with convergent square series) , while $L_2$ is the space of linear operators which fit better here ?

Comment: I am used to $L_2$ being the space of square-integrable functions on a domain and $l_2$ being the space of square-convergent sequences, so for me it is natural to denote the norm on the space of finite sequences defined by $\sqrt{\sum_{i}x_i^2}$ as the $l_{2}$-norm, and the norm induced by it on the space of operators as $l_{2}$ as well. I don't remember if this notation is standard.